# The composition of two continuous functions is discontinuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f(x, y)$ is defined on some neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$. If $u(x, y) = \sin f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$ then $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$

This statement is said to be false, but I cannot figure out why. Since $f(x, y) = \arcsin(\sin f(x, y))$ and $\arcsin(x)$ is continuous at each point of $[-1, 1]$ then $f(x, y)$ is a composition of two continuous functions $\arcsin x$ and $u(x, y)$. How can it be discontinuous? Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Your subject line as now written says "The composition of two continuous functions is discontinuous". In fact, a composition of two continuous functions is continuous. But the question doesn't say anything about a composition of two continuous functions being discontinuous; rather it is about a composition of a continuous function and a discontinuous function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy why? $\arcsin x$ is continuous,  $u(x,y)$ is continuous, but their composition isn't

Comment: @DF: $\arcsin$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, but it's not guaranteed that $\arcsin(\sin(z)) = z$. So $\arcsin(\sin f(x,y))$ will indeed always be continuous (even in the examples given in the answers), but it isn't the same function as $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @psmears yes, I've understood. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y)=\begin {cases} 0&x \ge 0\\ \pi& x \lt 0 \end {cases}$$
Then $\sin(f(x,y))=0$ is nicely continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\arcsin$ is not a proper inverse of $\sin$ (in general), because $\sin$ is not a bijection (at least not as a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$). For example, consider a function $f$ which, discontinuously, takes only the two values $\{0, 2\pi\}$. Then ${\sin} \circ f$ will be the zero function, which is obviously continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=2\pi$ if $x \geq 0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x < 0$. Your mistake is, the domain of '$\arcsin$' might be not $[-1,1]$. If the range of $f$ is not contained in any domain of $\arcsin$, then you cannot define the $\arcsin$ function.

Answer (score 1):

Your subject line as now written says "The composition of two continuous functions is discontinuous". In fact, a composition of two continuous functions is continuous. But the question doesn't say anything about a composition of two continuous functions being discontinuous; rather it is about a composition of a continuous function and a discontinuous function.

One could have, for example,
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for some values of $(x,y)$}, \\ \pi & \text{for some others.} \end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is not continuous, but $(x,y) \mapsto \sin f(x,y)$ is continuous since the value of that latter function is everywhere $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Take the horribly discontinuous function $f(x,y)$ defined to be $0$ when $x+y$ is rational and $2\pi$ otherwise.

What about $\sin(f(x,y))$ ?